# IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/dev/mem'

Tags: python, webserver

I'm using a *Zynq SoC* with *Ubuntu 16.04.03*, along with python *CGIHTTPServer* module in order to host a webpage that upon a button submit it runs a python script with a write to /dev/mem (i have a memory mapped custom PWM hardware peripheral I'd like to set a register value via a page served by the board).

**index.html** (fragment):

```
<iframe name="dummy" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="cgi-bin/textinput.py" method="POST" target="dummy">
    <input type="text" size="10" name="data" value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**textinput.py** (fragment)

```
with open ("/dev/mem", "r+b") as f:
  mem = mmap(f.fileno(), pwm_size, offset=pwm_offset)
```

When the web server attempts to run the script following the HTTP post, I get the error:

***Operation not permitted .. /dev/mem***

I've found many threads on this subject and have so far implemented the following "solutions", ranging from expected to "desperate measures".

1) my username is part of the group "gpio"
2) my username launches "python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000" on /var/www/html where index.html resides
3) textinput.py resides at /var/www/html/cgi-bin
4) /var/www (and its contents) have been chown to "gpio" and chmod g+rw
5) Similarly, /dev/mem has been given gpio group access.
5) I've "sudo visudo" and entered "gpio ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"

Regardless, I'm unable to have the python web server run *testinput*.py in the *CGI-bin* folder without complaining about permissions.

Needless to say, I'm able to successfully run the script via *"sudo python testinput.py"* and I'm able to /dev/mem with no issues.  But this is of no use since I need the web server to launch the script itself.

So I've run out of ideas.  **Anyone care to point out what I'm missing?**

I should further clarify that I'm *not* on a Raspberry Pi and not on Raspbian distro (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04), so I don't have a /dev/gpiomem to work with.

Comment: I've worked around the issue above by doing the following:

1) Start the server through a script through a script instead of the module call (that is, _sudo python server.py 8000_)

2) Embedded my _testinput.py_ code into _server.py_

Works like a charm.